# percentage of missing data in R gives error

Tags: r, bigdata, filtering, markers, genome

My data looks like this in R console:

> dim(df1)

```
[1] 54003   994
```

> df1[1:10, 1:10]

```
                        marker X1 X73 X88 X9 X17 X25 X33 X41 X49
1      1228104|F|0-8:C>T-8:C>T  0   0   0  0   0  NA   0   0   0
2    2277607|F|0-10:A>T-10:A>T NA   0   0 NA  NA  NA  NA   0   0
3  100023173|F|0-47:G>A-47:G>A  0   0   0 NA  NA  NA   0   0   0
4      1043336|F|0-7:A>G-7:A>G  1   1   1  0  NA   0   1   1   1
5    1212218|F|0-49:A>G-49:A>G  0   0   0  0   0   0   0   0   0
6    1019554|F|0-14:T>C-14:T>C  0   0   0  0  NA   0   0   0   0
7    1114675|F|0-18:T>C-18:T>C  0   0   0  0   0   0   0   0   0
8  100024550|F|0-16:G>A-16:G>A NA  NA  NA NA  NA  NA   0   0   0
9    1271969|F|0-22:T>A-22:T>A  0   0  NA  0  NA  NA   0   0   0
10     1106702|F|0-8:C>A-8:C>A  0  NA   0  0   0   0   0   0  NA
```

I filter my data based on this (FILTER1)

```
## % of missing per genotypes/samples
pmg <- apply(df1, 2, function(gid) sum(is.na(gid)) / length(gid))
length(pmg)

## dropping bad genotypes/ samples
df2 <-  data.frame(marker=df1[,1], df1[,pmg <= .2][,-1])
dim(df2)
#[1] 54003   909

## % of missing per snp
pms <- apply(df1[pmg <= .2, ], 1,
             function(snp) sum(is.na(snp)) / length(snp))
hist(pms)
length(pms)

# removing bad snps with high missing values 
df3 <- df2[pms <=0.2,]
dim(df3)
# [1] 37982   909
```

I try to run the same filter but this time I switch the order of two steps as follow (FILTER 2):

```
## % of missing per snp
pms <- apply(df1[pmg <= .2, ], 1,
             function(snp) sum(is.na(snp)) / length(snp))
hist(pms)
length(pms)

# removing bad snps with high missing values 
df2 <- df1[pms <=0.2,]
dim(df2)


## % of missing per genotypes/samples
pmg <- apply(df1, 2, function(gid) sum(is.na(gid)) / length(gid))
length(pmg)

## dropping bad genotypes/ samples 
df3 <-  data.frame(marker=df2[,1], df2[,pmg <= .2][,-1])
dim(df3)
```

When I run this code in FILTER 2;

```
> pms <- apply(df1[pmg <= .2, ], 1,
>              function(snp) sum(is.na(snp)) / length(snp))
```

It gives me this error:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(df1, pmg <= 0.2, ) : object 'pmg' not found

As you can see, I switched a few steps so the code should be modified too in order to work. But I couldn't figure out how.

Comment: as far as I can tell, you're trying to use `pmg` before you've defined it.  maybe move the `pmg <- apply(…` line of code up as well

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `pmg` before using it.
Just move this section to the top of you code:

```
## % of missing per genotypes/samples
pmg <- apply(df1, 2, function(gid) sum(is.na(gid)) / length(gid))
length(pmg)
```

Comment: Yes, I did that but the results in my console were the same. So basically it would be the same filter since it gives the same result